# ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out while pusing to github

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, push, ssh-keys

Since the last Ubuntu update I can't push using the cmd, and I don't know why (prob. a coincidence).

If I type:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

-> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

-> ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Right now I only have one pair of keys, the id_ed25519.pub added to my github account.
 And my ~/.ssh/config looks like:

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

What I don't understand is that If I use **SmartGit** for pushing, it ask me for the key and passphrase and I can push with it, using the id_ed25519 key.

- I don't have a firewall.
- I tried with other networks to check if my ISP was blocking those ports (22), but it did not work.
- If I change a repo from `git@github.com/username/repo` to `https://github.com/username/repo` I can push with username & password.

I did look for solutions, but none work for me, that's why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your SSH config, you would need to use `github.com` (IE. the "`Host`" name) as an URL, as [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port#enabling-ssh-connections-over-https):

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then you can test `ssh -Tv github.com`, with a remote URL for your repository:

```
ssh://github.com/username/repo
# or
github.com:username/repo
```

Comment: Added it in my config file and tried again the ssh -Tv command. Still getting the same error: connection time out. I'm completly lost.

Comment: @AJSantaeugenia Maybe there is a firewall rule which blocks egress connection, except for SmarGit?

Comment: Right now the firewall is inactive, sudo ufw status verbose ->Status: inactive.

Comment: @AJSantaeugenia Does this work? `curl -v telnet://github.com:443` ("work" meaning "shows 'Connected'")

Comment: Where in the `ssh -Tv` process does it time out?

Comment: @VonC Yes. It says connected. * Connected to github.com (140.82.121.3) port 443 (#0). With this can we confirm that is not port blocking?

Comment: @JimRedmond Just after debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [140.82.121.35] port 443.
The error I have is before that, is : debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files, but from what I understand, if that one is not defined, it uses the one in /home/user/~/.ssh/config, right?

Comment: @AJSantaeugenia Yes, it will use the `$HOME/.ssh/config` file. To be sure, change `Host github.com` with `Host gh`, and `test ssh -Tv gh`. That can only work if it uses `$HOME/.ssh/config`, where you define what `gh` stands for.

Comment: debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gh
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [140.82.121.35] port 443.

Looks like it's using /etc/ssh/ssh_config, in line 21 I have Host *.

Comment: @AJSantaeugenia That is why I suggested to change the host entry name. To force ssh to use your config, not the system one. But still, try and clean/comment line 21 of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in case it prevents connection.